# how to assign hex values into char type without null termination?

Tags: c

I would like to assign hex values into char type. Due to null (`\x00`) character, I cannot assign all hex values. Just 4 character can be assigned. How to assign all hex values in `(char*)data` ??

```
unsigned char data[100];
sprintf((char*)data,"\x30\x29\x02\x01\x00\x04\x06\x70\x75\x62\x6c\x69\x63\xa0");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, code cannot *assign* multiple values of an array with one assignment.  Code can initialize as is [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39902760/2410359).

Use a loop or `memcpy()` to *assign* multiple values.

```
unsigned char data[100];
#define SOURCE_DATA ("\x30\x29\x02\x01\x00\x04\x06\x70\x75\x62\x6c\x69\x63\xa0")
#define SOURCE_SIZE (sizeof SOURCE_DATA - 1)
memcpy(data, SOURCE_DATA, SOURCE_SIZE);
```

Comment: strlen command looks /0 (null). So problem comes strlen command as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have all your hex numbers available at compile time, you can assign them using curly brace initializer instead of a string literal:

```
unsigned char data[] = {
    0x30, 0x29 ,0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x06,
    0x70, 0x75, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, 0xa0
};
```